# (Pymongo) return Json data result, after interact MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to return Json result like below,
contains `is it successfully functioning` (use 0/1) , `modified contents` and `modified data count`

Json result:

> {"ok" : 1,  "msg" : [{ "name" : "Moma", "Age" : 33} , { "name" :
> "Kara", "Age" : 44} ],   "count": 2 }

The tried code below:
I tried to use `.inserted_count` and `.upserted_count` to count the number modified
and `x_new = json.dumps(x)` should transfer data into Json

seems I kind of know most logic, but not sure how to make logic work

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json

def init_db(ip, db, coll):
    try:
        myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' + ip + '/')
        mydb = myclient[db]
        mycol = mydb[coll]
        success_condition = "success on initializ operation"

    except Exception as e: 
        success_condition = "failed on initializ operation"
        
    return mydb, mycol, success_condition

  # ins_data = insert_db_data
def ins_data(one_or_many_bool, insert_values_json):
    try:    
        if one_or_many_bool == True:
            x = mycol.insert_many(insert_values_json)
        else:
            x = mycol.insert_one(insert_values_json)

        success_condition_insert = "success on ins_data operation"

    except Exception as e: 
        success_condition_insert = "failed on ins_data operation"

    return x , success_condition_insert

ip_input = input("Enter the ip: ")
exist_DB_name = input("Enter exist DB name: ")
exist_coll_name = input("Enter exist collection name: ")
mydb, mycol, success_condition  = init_db(ip_input, exist_DB_name, exist_coll_name)
print(success_condition)

insert_one_or_many = input("U are update one or many values? ( 1 for many, 0 for one ): ")
newvalues_str = input("Enter new values: ")

one_or_many_bool = bool(int(insert_one_or_many))
insert_values_json =json.loads(newvalues_str)

x , success_condition_insert = ins_data(one_or_many_bool, insert_values_json)
print(success_condition_insert)
x_new = json.dumps(x)
print(x_new)
print(type(x_new))
```

- the tried code output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.17_connect_mongoD_練習\test.py", line 56, in <module>
    x_new = json.dumps(x)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type InsertManyResult is not JSON serializable
```

**I want function can output in Json  like this**

> {"ok" : 1,  "msg" : [{ "name" : "Moma", "Age" : 33} , { "name" :
> "Kara", "Age" : 44} ],   "count": 2 }

Answer (score 0):

the `.modified_count` and `for modified_data in mycol.find().sort("_id", -1).limit(#num):` are the key

see below, I'm pretty close, here is what I solve

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json
def init_db(ip, db, coll):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' + ip + '/')
    mydb = myclient[db]
    mycol = mydb[coll]

    return mydb, mycol

def change_db_data(myquery_json, one_or_many_bool, newvalues_json ):
    
    if one_or_many_bool == True:
        x = mycol.update_many(myquery_json, newvalues_json)
    else:
        x = mycol.update_one(myquery_json, newvalues_json)
    return x

ip_input = input("Enter the ip: ")
exist_DB_name = input("Enter exist DB name: ")
exist_coll_name = input("Enter exist collection name: ")
mydb, mycol  = init_db(ip_input, exist_DB_name, exist_coll_name)

myquery_str = input("Enter ur query: ")
update_one_or_many = input("U are update one or many values? (ex:1 for many , 0 for one): ")
newvalues_str = input("Enter new values: ")

one_or_many_bool = bool(int(update_one_or_many))

myquery_json =json.loads(myquery_str)
newvalues_json =json.loads(newvalues_str)
x = change_db_data(myquery_json, one_or_many_bool, newvalues_json)
print(x)
print(x.modified_count, "documents updated.")

number_of_update_data = int(x.modified_count)

for modified_data in mycol.find().sort("_id", -1).limit(number_of_update_data):
  print(modified_data)

# 1 means success 
return_status_str = { "ok" : 1 , "msg" : modified_data , "count" : number_of_update_data}
print(return_status_str)
```

*and the ur expect output* (I haven't nicely print 3 modified data in `msg`, but there is close)

> {'ok': 1, 'msg': {'_id': ObjectId('6348d73be94317989175dc31'), 'name':
> 'Kim', 'ID': 0, 'Age': 44, 'time': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 17, 9,
> 11, 24), 'Update_ID': '99999'}, 'count': 3}